# How to use re to find consecutive space delimited single characters for each item in a large list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let say I have the following list
 `['Y M C A','cambridge m a','d m v office','t mobile']`
and want to convert it to
`['YMCA','cambridge ma','dmv office','t mobile']`

that is to detect all consecutive single characters followed by single space of different lengths (  greater than two). For example, the item `'d m v office'`, we should detect `**'d m v'**` and convert it to `**'dmv'**` but would leave `'t mobile store'` intact (only one single character).

I know I could loop through the list, split each item by space and look for single character items but does not sound very efficient. Is it possible to do it using regex and module re?  Once again the consecutive patterns could be of any length, greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import re

def trim_match_spaces(matchObj):
    return ''.join(matchObj.group(0).split())

templist = ['Y M C A', 'cambridge m a', 'd m v office', 't mobile', 'cambridge m a is far from the sun']

for index, word in enumerate(templist):
    templist[index] = re.sub(r'(\b(\w\s)+\w\b)', trim_match_spaces, word)

print templist
```

This prints

```
['YMCA', 'cambridge ma', 'dmv office', 't mobile', 'cambridge ma is far from the sun']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex `sub` works for me:

```
text = 'd m v office'
out = re.sub(r'(.) (.)(?:\s+|$)',r'\1\2',text)
print(out) #<-- prints 'dmv office'
```

The first argument is the pattern to match, which has 3 capture groups, the first two being the `(.) (.)` that match single characters separated by spaces. The `(?:\s+|$)` matches a space or end of string. The second argument says to replace the hit with the first two capture groups, and the third argument is the text input.

Comment: what if the spaced-out text is in the middle of the string, e.g. `'cambridge m a is far from the sun'`?

Comment: ah you are right, it doesn't work on this example, I'll work on fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a regex you can use:

```
\b(\w(?:[\b ]\w)+)\b
```

You can check the regex101 example here:
https://regex101.com/r/WCGE6q/1